# My android studio shows error in the file but it has absolutely 0 build issues, 0 errors in logcat and event log

Tags: java, android-studio, compiler-errors

My android studio shows me this while cloned a repo. I am able to open the app in Emulator though. No errors in logcat, not in event log and also 0 build issues. Can any one help me how to resolve these showing errors.TIA.

[See this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhSPY.png)

[This one too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ILnS.png)

Comment: When you view these files, look at the top right corner of the editor, above the scroll bar. Is there an eye icon there? Or is it a red square?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - Thank you for responding. I closed my android studio and switched to some other branch in the repo. When I came back to this repo, it was resolved. I am not sure why though but no more errors now.

Comment: So now I get this again and again. I see errors and this time they are not resolving on their own. I see red icon in circle shape with exclamation mark in it. So every error, it says create AppCompatActivity Class, unused imports etc. Please help. Thankyou